# Pull div content to external display in electron

Tags: electron

In my project, I need to achieve a very special function: pull div content to external display, div content include text, image, video, other html ..., [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/farAf.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [screen module](https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/screen.md) to detect the display and create another window and move it into there.

Comment: I need copy div content to external display, eg: Paused the video, it stopped at external display,